# architectures of COBOL and Java

Tags: java, cobol

Can anyone tell me the differnces in styles and architectures between these very differenct approaches please?

Comment: There's a random tag if ever I saw one.

Comment: Wow, I didn't even know we had a cobol tag.. and yea, the languages are very different.. Its strict oop vs. strict structural/imperative

Comment: And it sounds like a homework question ...

Comment: I knew we had a COBOL tag, I just avoid it scrupulously.

Answer (score 2):

These are totally different languages intended for different purposes. COBOL is early days language for financial/accounting purposes very strict about program flow. Java is something totally different which is an evolved OOPL for general purpose applicaation development. I dont see any point in comparing COBOL and Java. let me know what exactly you were looking for  and to help you.